# Tsallis $q$-Gaussian and applications

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Why is not $q$-Gaussian distribution merely the substitution of q exponential into the gaussian function?, i.e. substitution of equ.2 in equ.1. Where would there be three cases as below. When to use each, the direct substitution and the defined $q$-Gaussian function? different applications?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, the $q$-Gaussian is defined as closely as possible to a direct swap of exponential for $q$-exponential as you could hope.  To the extent it looks like that isn't true, it is only because in the $q$-Gaussian case, the shape factor ("covariance") and the normalization have been written differently.  For the Gaussian, the normalization $A$ was written in the numerator and for the $q$-Gaussian, the normalization $C_q$ was written in the denominator.  Likewise, for the Gaussian, you have factors of $w$ (in the notation of the question) in the denominators for the Gaussian and corresponding factors of $\sqrt{\beta}$ in the numerators.

Now this notation does hide some things, some of which are related to the normalization choices:

1. The $q$-exponential is only defined over a bounded subset of the real line for $q<1$, and so the distribution there is fundamentally different than in the unbounded cases.  This is enforced by the innocuous looking $+$ subscript in the definition of the $q$-exponential.
2. In the "fat-tail" cases of $1 < q < 3$, the distribution goes to 0 at infinity with power-law tails rather than the exponential decay in the normal Gaussian.
3. Points #1 & #2 give rise to the completely different forms of the normalization factors in the different cases.
4. A point never well-emphasized with these distributions is that the transition between the cases is not defined by a properly smooth limit in $q$.  This is especially true in the limit $q \rightarrow 1^-$ where $q$ approaches 1 from below because the truncation to the finite domain is not a smooth operation.  It's also true, though more subtly so, in the limit $q \rightarrow 1^+$ because there's infinite Fisher distance between the fat-tails and the exponential tails.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, supposing that by substitution of equ.2 into equ.1 you mean $e_q(g(x))$ where
$$
g(x)=\frac{A}{w\sqrt{\pi/2}}e^{-2(x-\xi_C)^2/w^2}
$$
and $e_q(x)=[(1+(1-q)x)]_+^{1/(1-q)}\,:$ Since $g(\pm\infty)=0$ we get
$e_q(g(\pm\infty))=1$ regardless what $q$ is. For a function to be a distribution function on $(-\infty,+\infty)$ it is however necessary that its limits at $\pm\infty$ are zero.

For further applications of q-Gaussian distributions, see this [thesis](http://www.tml.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/team/ghoshdastidar/pdf/ME_Report.pdf).

Comment: Be warned Eq. (1.1) in the linked thesis is missing a $-$ sign.

Comment: I apologise, I meant the opposite; i.e. using the q exponential formula; power law tail, instead of the exponential in the gaussian formula.